# Creating fire severity rasters using Google Earth Engine & Parks et al. 2018

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using an available code on Google Earth Engine that takes wildfire polygons that have a `Year` and `UniqueFireID` in the attributes and created fire severity rasters ('dnbr', 'dnbr_w_offset','rbr', 'rbr_w_offset','rdnbr', 'rdnbr_w_offset')

The code can be found here
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c76157be827be2f24570df50cca427e9

I've been running most of the polygons through with no problems but some large batches come up with:

> Error: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=00000000000000000032):
> Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required.

and I have also encountered another:

> Error: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=0000000000000000000b):
> Image.select: Pattern 'preNBR' did not match any bands.

I'm assuming the second Error is that it can't find a good enough image for preNBR and then can't make the rest of the sets because preNBR is the starting point but I have no idea how to troubleshoot the first error.

I have only made one small change to the original code in that I am only calling the code to create the 'rdnbr_w_offset' instead of 'dnbr', 'dnbr_w_offset','rbr', 'rbr_w_offset','rdnbr', 'rdnbr_w_offset'

I am pretty new to Earth Engine and have minimal coding/scripting experience with R and Python.

```
// Script to develop and export 6 fire severity metrics (see list below) for each of 18 fires across the western US. 
//    Polygon-based fire perimeters were created by the Monitoring Trends in Burn Severity (MTBS) program (www.mtbs.gov). 
//    Script by Morgan Voss and Than Robinson - University of Montana
//    with revisions by Lisa Holsinger - U.S. Forest Service Rocky Mountain Research Station
//    May 2018 
//    For updates or questions on this code, please can contact:  
//        Lisa Holsinger, lisamholsinger@fs.fed.us
//        Sean Parks, sean_parks@fs.fed.us
//
// Fire Severity metrics created include:
//    dNBR:        delta normalized burn ratio
//    RdNBR:       relativezed delta normalized burn ratio
//    RBR:         relativized burn ratio
//    dNBRoffset:  dNBR with an offset to account for inter-annual differences in phenology between pre- and post-fire imagery.
//    RdNBRoffset: RdNBR with offset (as above)
//    RBRoffset:   RBR with offset (as above)

////////////////////// IMPORTANT - PLEASE READ BELOW ////////////////////////////////
// 1) When 'Run' Button is hit, it may take a few minutes to populate tasks 
//    and the browser may become unresponsive. In this case, the browser 
//    will bring up an option to 'Wait' while list of tasks are completed, 
//    which should be confirmed.
//
// 2) Create a folder called 'fires' in Google Drive before running exports,
//    otherwise, an error 'More than one folder with specified name [fires] found'
//    may occur.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//--------------------       INPUTS       ------------------------------//
// import shapefile with fire polygons as a feature collection - these must have the following standard attributes  
//    as distributed by MTBS:  Fire_ID and Year
//    Note, we use Fire_ID as unique identifier rather than 'Fire_Name' attribute which has duplicate names for different fires
var fires = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mtd25/fires/1996");
//var fires_all = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mtd25/fires/SW_Fires_lessthan1000acres_1984_2019");
//print(fires)
//var fires = fires_all.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Year', 1986));
//print(fires)
//Map.addLayer(fires, )

// specify fire severity metrics to create
var bandList = ['rdnbr_w_offset'];
//var bandList = ['dnbr', 'dnbr_w_offset','rbr', 'rbr_w_offset','rdnbr', 'rdnbr_w_offset'];
// Enter beginning and end days for imagery season as julian dates
var startday = 91;
var endday   = 181;

//  visualize fire perimeters
Map.setCenter(-115,41.5, 5);
Map.addLayer(fires, {color: 'Red'}, "Fire perimeters");

//--------------------    END OF INPUTS   ----------------------------//


//--------------------     PROCESSING     ----------------------------//
//-------- Initialize variables for fire perimeters  -----------------//
// create two lists: one with fire names and the other with fire IDs 
var fireID    = ee.List(fires.aggregate_array('Fire_ID')).getInfo();
print(fireID)
var nFires = fireID.length;

//------------------- Image Processing for Fires Begins Here -------------//
// Landsat 5, 7, and 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1 collections
var ls8SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR'),
    ls7SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR'),
    ls5SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR'),
    ls4SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR');

/////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTIONS TO CREATE NBR
/////////////////////////////////

// Returns vegetation indices for LS8
var ls8_Indices = function(lsImage){
  var nbr = lsImage.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B7']).toFloat();
  var qa = lsImage.select(['pixel_qa']);
  return nbr.addBands([qa])
          .select([0,1], ['nbr', 'pixel_qa'])
          .copyProperties(lsImage, ['system:time_start']);
  };
  
// Returns vegetation indices for LS4, LS5 and LS7
var ls4_7_Indices = function(lsImage){
  var nbr = lsImage.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B7']).toFloat();
  var qa = lsImage.select(['pixel_qa']);
  return nbr.addBands([qa])
          .select([0,1], ['nbr', 'pixel_qa'])
          .copyProperties(lsImage, ['system:time_start']);
  };

// Mask Landsat surface reflectance images
// Creates a mask for clear pixels 
var lsCfmask = function(lsImg){
  var quality =lsImg.select(['pixel_qa']);
  var clear = quality.bitwiseAnd(8).eq(0) // cloud shadow
                .and(quality.bitwiseAnd(32).eq(0) // cloud
                .and(quality.bitwiseAnd(4).eq(0) // water
                .and(quality.bitwiseAnd(16).eq(0)))); // snow
  return lsImg.updateMask(clear).select([0])                                    
            .copyProperties(lsImg, ['system:time_start']);
};

// Map functions across Landsat Collections
var ls8 = ls8SR.map(ls8_Indices)
                .map(lsCfmask);
var ls7 = ls7SR.map(ls4_7_Indices)
                .map(lsCfmask); 
var ls5 = ls5SR.map(ls4_7_Indices)
                .map(lsCfmask); 
var ls4 = ls4SR.map(ls4_7_Indices)
                .map(lsCfmask); 
                
// Merge Landsat Collections
var lsCol = ee.ImageCollection(ls8.merge(ls7).merge(ls5).merge(ls4));

// ------------------ Create and Export Fire Severity Imagery for each fire -----------------//
var indices = ee.ImageCollection(fires.map(function(ft){
  // use 'Fire_ID' as unique identifier
  var fName = ft.get("Fire_ID");

  // select fire
  var fire = ft;
  var fireBounds = ft.geometry().bounds();
  
  // create pre- and post-fire NBR imagery
  var fireYear = ee.Date.parse('YYYY', fire.get('Year'));
  var preFireYear = fireYear.advance(-1, 'year');
  var postFireYear = fireYear.advance(1, 'year');
  var preFireIndices = lsCol.filterBounds(fireBounds)
                          .filterDate(preFireYear, fireYear)
                          .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(startday, endday))
                          .mean()
                          .rename('preNBR');
 
  var postFireIndices = lsCol.filterBounds(fireBounds)
                          .filterDate(postFireYear, fireYear.advance(2, 'year'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(startday, endday))
                          .mean()
                          .rename('postNBR');
                          
  var fireIndices = preFireIndices.addBands(postFireIndices);
  
  // create fire severity indices    
  // calculate dNBR  
  var burnIndices = fireIndices.expression(
              "(b('preNBR') - b('postNBR')) * 1000")
              .rename('dnbr').toFloat().addBands(fireIndices);

  // calculate dNBR with Offset developed from 180-m ring outside the fire perimeter
  var ring   = fire.buffer(180).difference(fire);
  var burnIndices2 = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(burnIndices.select('dnbr').reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: ring.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e9
    }).get('dnbr'))).rename('offset').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices); 

  var burnIndices3 = burnIndices2.expression(
            "b('dnbr') - b('offset')").
            rename('dnbr_w_offset').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices2);

  // calculate RBR  
  var burnIndices4 = burnIndices3.expression(
            "b('dnbr') / (b('preNBR') + 1.001)")
            .rename('rbr').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices3);
  
  // calculate RBR with offset
  var burnIndices5 = burnIndices4.expression(
            "b('dnbr_w_offset') / (b('preNBR') + 1.001)")
            .rename('rbr_w_offset').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices4);

  // calculate RdNBR
  var burnIndices6 = burnIndices5.expression(
    "(b('preNBR') < 0.001) ? 0.001" + 
      ": b('preNBR')")
      .sqrt().rename('preNBR2').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices5);

  var burnIndices7 = burnIndices6.expression(
    "(b('dnbr') / sqrt(b('preNBR2')))")
    .rename('rdnbr').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices6);

  // calculate RdNBR with offset
  var burnIndices8 = burnIndices7.expression(
            "b('dnbr_w_offset') / sqrt(b('preNBR2'))")
            .rename('rdnbr_w_offset').toFloat().addBands(burnIndices7);

  burnIndices8 = burnIndices8.select(bandList);
  return burnIndices8.set({
                        'fireID' : ft.get('Fire_ID'),
                        'fireName' : ft.get('Fire_Name'),
                        'fireYear' : ft.get('Year')
  }); 
}));

// // Export fire indices for each fire  
var nBands = bandList.length;

for (var j = 0; j < nFires; j++){
  var id   = fireID[j];
  var Name = id;
  var fireExport = ee.Image(indices.filterMetadata('fireID', 'equals', id).first());
  var fireBounds = ee.Feature(fires.filterMetadata('Fire_ID', 'equals', id).first()).geometry().bounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < nBands; i++) {
    var bandExport = bandList[i];  
    var exportImg = fireExport.select(bandExport);
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: exportImg,
      description: Name + '_' + bandExport,
      fileNamePrefix: Name + '_' + bandExport,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      scale: 30,
      crs: "EPSG:4326",
      folder: 'fires',      
      region: fireBounds
  }); 
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required.

This error happens when it gets `null` (equivalent to an omitted parameter) instead of a proper value. In situations like this, that usually happens because there is no data, such as because you called `.get('x')` on a feature or dictionary that doesn't have a property/key named `'x'`.

The obvious candidate is your

```
ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(....get('dnbr')))
```

To debug this problem, modify your `map` that constructs `indices` to return features whose properties are things like the list of band names in `burnIndices` and the properties of the dictionary returned by `reduceRegion` (instead of trying to compute the desired image), print the resulting collection, and see which bands you're getting. If you need more help, first reduce your script to a simpler form that still produces the error (even if it does not calculate anything scientifically meaningful).